# foam and bubbles particles in mantaflow just look like white points moving around

Tags: particles, fluid-simulation, mantaflow

[image: imagedesc]

viewport screen. those particles look the same when rendered. when combined export is turned on they completely disappear. yes the particles are rendering as objects and they have a material.

heres the blend file
[image]

Comment: did you set render as object? did you gave them materials? the provided information isn't enough...so please provide blend file so we can check it out...or watch these: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ufgrEMggdLg

Comment: i've added more information and also the blend file

Comment: next time you add a blend file, please do file -> external data -> pack resources before uploading, so we can help you better. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1. you have to set render as object and then e.g. choose an icosphere so that it will be rendered.

[image]

2. each of your rendered objects need to have a material (maybe change it to a plain red just to see it works and it doesn't render as white). Afterwards (when there is not plain white anymore) you can change the material you want to have (if it's then white again, your material has a problem...)